# Page 43 of Questions

Tags: discussion, questions

The last question on page 43 of questions (13/3/2015), which I have assumed was the first question ever asked on Poker Beta, is marked as a duplicate. How so?

Q is [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-odds-i-will-hit-my-flush)

Comment: Keep in mind that sometimes questions do get deleted. Now, we are restricted/forbidden from deleting questions that are marked as duplicate. But back then there was no such restriction.

Comment: so you deleted the first ever post on Poker SE?

Answer (score 2):

On any stack site, an older question may be marked as a duplicate because perhaps a new question is of better quality, describes the problem better etc. and has received better answers.

[Opinions on closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/opinions-on-closing-an-older-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question)

Comment: i rest my case.